# Unable to open a Standard User Account on a newly installed Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7

I was having a lot of troubles in my system, so yesterday I reinstalled Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit in my Laptop. Today I created a new Standard User account, the account is created but when I log off from the Administrator account and  Log in to the standard user, it seems like logging in for a moment and then immediately logs off.

What's wrong? What's the possibility? Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

See the video of what exactly happens at: http://youtu.be/IvRAIiWOoPY
[Kindly watch the video with the annotations given by me]

These are the two errors that I repeatedly see in the Event Log:

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards.
>
> DETAIL -
> 1 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-2548324497-3894290438-2285999279-1003:
> Process 3964 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2548324497-3894290438-2285999279-1003\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer\CodeIdentifiers

And the second one is:

> The Windows logon process has failed to spawn a user application. Application name: . Command line parameters: C:\Program Files (x86)\iSafe\wpk.exe.

The file refereed to here is a key-logger which I had installed and again un-installed yesterday. It's a trial version of the key logger and I have used it multiple times before, without any trouble what so ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still some reference to your key logger. Try sysinternals autoruns to find and remove the reference. The other message might indicate that there still is some process for standard user. Be sure to check 'show processes for all users' in task manager.

Comment: There is still some reference to your key logger. Try sysinternals autoruns to find and remove the reference. The other message might indicate that there still is some process for standard user. Be sure to check 'show processes for all users' in task manager.